# Database cleaner strategy in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, rspec-rails

Is it possible to check what the database cleaner strategy is at any point in the test cases?

How will I come to know which type of strategy is used in the test cases?

```
config.before(:example) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
end

config.before(:example, type: :feature, js: true) do
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
end

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature 'Login Feature', type: :feature do
  it 'invalid user login fail' do
    a = create(:normal_user, role: AdminType::OWNER)
    visit('/')
  end
end
```

Here, I have mentioned type as a feature in the top most `describe` block (Example Group), not in the example. But I have configured my database cleaner to use truncation strategy on feature type example for others using transaction strategy.

Which type of strategy will the database cleaner use, truncation or transaction?

If it uses truncation strategy, then I think that all examples under `type: feature` will be considered `type: feature` examples. Am I right?

How will I check what the current strategy is (for example, by seeing the test log)?

Comment: Why do you need to know? Do your tests depend on one specific strategy? And fail on another? Why? I would argue that you test should always pass no matter how you setup your database.

Comment: @spickermann I would like to know/confirm whether it is using correct startgey as per my database cleaner configuration if there is a way. .so all exmaples under  exambl groups which are tagged with type:feature  will be considered type:feature example or not ??

Comment: `RSpec.featuure` already adds the `type: feature` metadata so you don’t need to specify it again. Also, what version of Rails are you using? (DatabaseCleaner isn’t generally needed in Rails 5.1 and above)

Comment: Oh great.Thanks for the info. @ThomasWalpole I am using Rails 5.0.2. So all examples under Rspec.feature block will  be considered  feature type examble?? In other words all  examples under Rspec.feature block will have type: feature metadata?? Whats advantages using  system spec instead of Feature Spec??. If i use rails custom system test casesails 5.1 or later, i need to use only minitest syantax in the test cases??

Comment: And one more doubt, In rails 5.1 or later, if i want to use rspec with system spec, then do i need  Database cleaner gem or not?? @ThomasWalpole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - any test inside the `RSpec.feature` block will have `tpye: :feature` metadata unless it overrides by specifying another type.  System specs and feature specs are basically the same thing, just Rails added an extra layer of abstraction on system tests (`driven_by`, etc)

In Rails 5.1+ for feature or system tests, even if using RSpecs system tests rather than the Rails minitest based system tests, DatabaseCleaner is generally not needed. This is because Rails 5.1 added automatic sharing of the database connection between all threads in the test process while in the test environment. If you were needing a separate process to access the database during tests then you would still need DatabaseCleaner, but that's not common especially with beginning projects.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I have one last doubt.As you have told, generally we dont need Database cleanner until separate process is trying to access the database during tests.In case of  syetem/feature test suit for login with the use of  Devise gem, Do i need the Database cleaner gem or not.Pease see my code below

Comment: require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature 'Login Feature', type: :feature do
    let(:user) { create(:normal_user, role: AdminType::OWNER) }
 it 'valid user login  and log out' do
    visit('/')
    within('#new_user') do
      fill_in 'user[email]', with: user.email
      fill_in 'user[password]', with: user.password
    end
    click_button 'SIGN IN'
    expect(page).to have_content(user.name.present? ? user.name : user.email)
  end
end

Comment: In this , if i run this, it is failing.
Here i am visting root page
then creatted the use  and fill up user details in the UI
and then click the login button
During ayuthentication by devise gem, the user which i have creaed  is become the unauthorized one.I would like to know the reason

Is it because the user creation is in sepate process and devise authentication is in seprate process or any other reason? If any , please advise me

Comment: @Jegan I'm sorry I don't understand what you're asking, and it appears to not be to do with the current question. Stop trying to expand the current question and instead create a new question, if you have one, with enough information for people to be able to answer it - pasting multiple lines of code in comments is basically unreadable.